# Remove jetpack compose testtag for release builds

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am searching a way to remove jetpack compose testtags in release builds.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's something out-of-the-box on `rc02`.
But you can do the following:

```
fun Modifier.testTagDebug(tag: String): Modifier =
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) this.testTag(tag) else this
```

Comment: I did something similar by creating a method `testableSemantics()` in different BuildTypes folders and in release I am just returning this modifier.
But with both solutions we still have all the tag strings in production code.

Comment: you mean the testTag values are still there even if not set @PeterG?